# How do you pass method params in Ruby which can be used as the name of existing methods?

Tags: ruby, selenium, automated-tests, watir, watir-webdriver

Background: I'm using a DSL for automated UI testing in Ruby called Watir-Webdriver.

I want to write a very re-usable method that passes or fails when a specific HTML element is present. Here is what I have so far:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'rspec'

b = Watir::Browser.new

def display_check(element_type,unique_element,expectation) 
 if expectation == "yes"
  b.send(element_type).((:id or :class or :name or :value),/#{Regexp.escape(unique_element)}/).exists?.should == true
 else
  b.send(element_type).((:id or :class or :name or :value),/#{Regexp.escape(unique_element)}/).exists?.should == false
  end
end
```

I can understand that "div" in this example is a string passed as a method argument. But in the context of the dsl, "div" (minus the quotes) is also a Watir-webdriver method. So I guess I need to somehow convert the string to an eligible watir-webdriver method

I basically want to do the following to determine if an element exists.

```
 display_check("div","captcha","no")
```

Since I'll be looking for select_lists, divs, radio buttons etc, it would be very useful to specify the element type as an option instead of having it hard coded to the method.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `send`, the first parameter is the method name and the following parameters are the parameters to pass to the method. See [doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send).

So your `b.send` should be more like:

```
b.send(element_type, :id, /#{Regexp.escape(unique_element)}/).exists?
```

To find an element where one of the attributes (id, class, etc) is a certain value, you can try the following. Basically it iterates through each of the attributes until an element is found.

```
def display_check(b, element_type, unique_element, expectation) 
    element_exists = false
    [:id, :class, :name, :value].each do |attribute|
        if b.send(element_type, attribute, /#{Regexp.escape(unique_element)}/).exists?
            element_exists = true
            break
        end
    end

    if expectation == "yes"
        element_exists.should == true
    else
        element_exists.should == false
    end
end
```

Comment: That worked. I guess I misunderstood how the send method works. Big thanks!